# How to import request Option in angular8

Tags: angular

Here is the model:- It's a service that connect with back-end controller 
And it can't find requestOption

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http'
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
private baseUrl: string ='http://localhost:8080/api';
private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
private options = new RequestOptions({headers:this.headers});
constructor() { }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way

https://www.positronx.io/angular-8-httpclient-http-tutorial-build-consume-restful-api/

```
baseurl = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  // Http Headers
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }



    // POST
      CreateYourBug(data): Observable<Bug_Class> {
        return this.http.post<Bug_Class>(this.baseurl + '/bugtracking/', JSON.stringify(data), this.httpOptions)
        .pipe(
          retry(1),
          catchError(this.errorHandl)
        )
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as `RequestOptions` provided by `@angular/common/http` package.

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api';
  private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private options = { headers: this.headers };
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getData() {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl, this.options);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this `options` object is not exposed as a named interface so you can't really provide a type safety to `this.options` variable. (I meant `private options: HttpRequestOptions = {...};`)
[image]

```js
options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders | {
            [header: string]: string | string[];
        };
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams | {
            [param: string]: string | string[];
        };
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'text';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    }
```